# Accessing files outside the root directing

Tags: php, linux, apache, filesystems, debian

My client asked me to do a website where a user can enter a path on the machine, PHP should scan the path and load all the media files in the directory and subdirectories. The user can enter any path, Desktop, or external drives, whatever, outside the root directory. That's what the client wants and he's running on Linux.

I told him php can't access files outside the root, he said yes it can, he said I should use some proxy and he sent me this script

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<?PHP
session_start();
function getFileList($dir)
  {
    // array to hold return value
    $retval = array();

    // add trailing slash if missing
    if(substr($dir, -1) != "/") $dir .= "/";

    // open pointer to directory and read list of files
    $d = @dir($dir) or die("getFileList: Failed opening directory $dir for reading");
    while(false !== ($entry = $d->read())) {
      // skip hidden files
      if($entry[0] == ".") continue;
      if(is_dir("$dir$entry")) {
        $retval[] = array(
          "name" => "$entry/"
        );
      } elseif(is_readable("$dir$entry")) {
        $retval[] = array(
          "name" => "$entry"
        );
      }
    }
    $d->close();

    return $retval;
  }
$dirlist = getFileList("F:\uni\M2\Thesis\hmayed\ali\songs wav");

  // output file list in HTML TABLE format
  echo "<table border=\"1\">\n";
  echo "<thead>\n";
  echo "<tr><th>Name</th></tr>\n";
  echo "</thead>\n";
  echo "<tbody>\n";
  foreach($dirlist as $file) {
    echo "<form action=\"MusicP.php\" Method = \"POST\" \">\n";

   echo "<input value =\" F:\\uni\\M2\\Thesis\\hmayed\\ali\\songs wav\\{$file['name']}\" type = \"submit\" name= \"submit\" id=\"{$file['name']}\">\n";

    echo "</tr>\n";
  }
  echo "</form>\n";
  echo "</table>\n\n";


?>
<audio src = "File:///F:\uni\M2\Thesis\songs\1.mp3" type= "audio/mp3" controls>
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

So my questions:

- Does this script or this type of scripts work? Is the project
  feasible?
- And what happens if I create an apache virtual server to `/` would it read all the file system? I have never tried it.

Comment: Both approaches are possible, both are equally insecure. The only thing that will cause technical issues are file system permissions. Using extensions like `sudo` you can also work around that, but things obviously gets even more insecure. For example that allows to read the passwords for the system accounts. Not a good thing, is it?

Comment: @arkascha he's just doing a demonstration on raspberry pi, not worrying about security

Comment: I don't see why one should not care about security. I would not want to have such a zombie in my network. But if you insist... May we ask you to publish the URL to the system? We all would like to use it...

Comment: @arkascha it will only run on localhost, no public url

Comment: There is some ambiguity here, when talking about a root directory.  I think you mean the document root.  As long as the user under which the script is running has read and list permissions to the directory given then it doesn't matter if it's in document root or not.  Perhaps you are thinking about the open_basedir directive.  http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir

Comment: @Progrock Yes, interesting I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a Php script to proxy to a shell command to get a file list:

```
<?php

print nl2br(shell_exec('find /tmp'));
```

Replace /tmp in the example above with a user contributed value.

Further, to play media files you could do something like the following (please bear in mind the security ramifications):

```
<?php

$file = isset($_GET['file']) ? $_GET['file'] : null;

if($file) serve_file($file);

function serve_file($file) {
    header('Content-Type: audio/mpeg');
    readfile($file);
    exit;
}

$dir   = '/tmp';
$music = shell_exec("find $dir -name '*.mp3'");
$music = explode("\n", $music);
$music = array_filter($music);

// html here...

foreach($music as $file) {?>
    <a href="?file=<?php echo urlencode($file) ?>"><?php echo $file; ?></a><br />
<?
}
```

Comment: say i used find to `find` mp3s how to load them in a php list so i could play them in a jquery player? or are you suggesting to use mplayer?

Comment: @Lynob that's another question. Sorry I missed that part.